# Modify webapp fullscreen bookmarklet for iPhone 5

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, bookmarklet

How is it possible to modify this bookmarklet which activates the webclip app-mode so that iOS will display it in 4 inch fullscreen?: http://cl.ly/text/1H1b3E3K3T0V
I've already read about the changes you need to make in html when optimizing a page but I didn't get it right with this script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that adding the meta tag "apple-mobile-web-app-capable" after the page had loaded is not going to work. Safari is likely not expecting this to change after the fact and therefor is not watching for a change. In other words, I would predict that you can't use a bookmarklet to do what you are trying to do in such a direct manner.

I suspect that adding the "apple-touch-startup-image" will work because Safari is not checking for this information until the user chooses to create a home screen shortcut.

As a possible work around to the problem, you might consider is somehow trying to recreate the page using the modified HTML. The bookmarklet might modify the DOM like above, then create a new blank tab with window.open() and set its contents equal to the current document.documentElement.outerHTML. This is just a suggestion off top of my head and I have not tested it.